# AutoUpdater.Net Not Overwriting File

Tags: c#, .net, auto-update

I have uploaded my valid xml, and I can confirm that the new file is being downloaded to the users temp dir.  However, the current file is not being over-wrote.

I added the reference to `AutoUpdate.Net.dll`
and used this to install it `PM> Install-Package Autoupdater.NET.Official`
And this is the syntax I am using

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Changing settings
    AutoUpdater.OpenDownloadPage = true;
    AutoUpdater.ShowRemindLaterButton = true;

    //Checking versioning info on Server
    AutoUpdater.Start("http://madeupURL/AutoUpdater.xml");
}
```

However, mine looks nothing like the images from the github directory.  I only get a popup telling me there is a new version, I click download, then the updater displays, and the file is downloaded.

My syntax has no compile errors nor debug errors either.

What is keeping my syntax from over-writing the file?

Comment: Did you check logs in **eventvwr.msc**, Is there any kind of permission issue? Or may be files you are trying to overwrite are in use, so can't be overwritten by windows.

Comment: Did you sort it out? Have you tried to run the app with Administrator privileges?